# using audioclip in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, game-engine

```
AudioSource ses;
public AudioClip hizSes;
public AudioClip s110;
void Start()
{
    ses = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    maxHiz = 110;
}
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
    {
        if(Araba.speed >= -maxHiz+2)
        {
            ses.clip = s110;
            ses.Stop();

            ses.clip = hizSes;
            ses.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            ses.clip = s110;
            ses.Play();
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp("w") || Araba.speed <= -maxHiz+2)
    {
        ses.clip = hizSes;
        ses.Stop();
    }
}
```

The speed in the "Araba" script varies between -20 and -110. When -110, the hizSes should stop and the s110 clip should work. hizSes stops but s110 does not work. (There is no mistake in the audio file.)

```
ses.clip = s110;
ses.Play();
```

I want the s110 clip to play when Araba.speed is -110.

Comment: Btw: For `Stop`ing the AudioSource there is no need to assign the `clip`. It will stop whatever is currently playing, not what is assigned in `clip` anyway